# Pointing a Subdomain to an AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

Im working on the Staging environment with AWS. I would like to point a Subdomain to an AWS EC2 Instance while keeping my DNS Nameserver service(Not AWS).

In the DNS Nameserver service, I added subdomain (A record) and pointed to the public ip in AWS EC2 Instance. Unfortunately, Im still unable to browse the staging with the subdomain (after 5 hour). Is that any step i had miss out?

Just to summarise the situation:

- I do have DNS Nameserver service (not AWS service)
- The Nameserver working currently
- In the DNS nameserver, i already pointed the subdomain to AWS public IP address
- I configure my DNS Nameserver service with cPanel

Comment: if you provide real (sub)domain name, it would be easier to troubleshoot

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with AWS but Nameserver config issue.
What DNS server you are using, what is the DNS record looks like. Mask them with other name when you post them.

Comment: @mootmoot I'm edit the DNS record in cPanel and included the snapshot in the post.

Comment: I assume i. you have a DNS server running ii. In you domain registrar, you already point the Nameserver to that particular DNS.

Comment: Please rearrange your question  in point form. After I read your edited question, I am confused.  Please clarify i. Your run your DNS Nameserver service?  ii. Is the Nameserver working currently? iii. Did you put your DNS nameserver IP address in your domain registrar record ?

Comment: @mootmoot question rearrange. Thanks

Comment: Did you try `curl http://<your-ec2-public-ip-address>/index.html` . If not, please check the EC2 instance Security Group, you need to allow inbound connection to all for port 80 and 443".